# How can I get a black overlay for my WPF MVVM Canvas of BitmapImages?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mvvm

I have a 10x10 grid and a canvas that spans all of that. The canvas is the items panel of an items control. The items are bound to a collection of BitmapImages as I basically need an image and then a black overlay somehow (black should cover the whole grid0. I also eventually need the user to be able to click on a given cell and then make that cell only show the image underneath the black overlay. So should the black be another bitmapimage or is there an easier way to do this with the grid somehow?

I can post the view model if that helps.

Xaml:

```
<Grid
    ShowGridLines="{Binding ShowGridLines}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <ItemsControl
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="10"
        Grid.RowSpan="10"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsToShowInCanvas}"
        Visibility="{Binding UploadButtonVisibility, Converter={StaticResource NotVisibilityConverter}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image
                    Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: If an Image is supposed to occupy a Grid cell, why don't you use a Grid as ItemsPanel, and bind Grid.Column and Grid.Row in the ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like a memory game? I'm not convinced that you really need a black overlay. I think you just need a way to toggle a screen area between an image and a black rectangle.

Comment: Like grek40 suggested, a black rectangle is much more easy to handle. And I would use one rectangle by cell (basically I would create a usercontrol that contains the black rectangle and the image to show/hide, and instantiate it in each cell.).

Comment: @Bob A UserControl is certainly overkill. A Rectangle and an Image element could easily be declared in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens Sorry for the late reply but each cell will not contain a separate image. One image is supposed to span all of the grid cells. The idea is that the image will be a map and the overlay is supposed to show what has been explored.